# "Unable to parse string " " at position ####" en una base de datos grande

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Estoy usando una base de datos CSV de estrellas y estoy intentando filtrarla, pero al momento de intentar convertir el dtype de una columna a "float" sale un error debido a que no hay un valor en determinada hilera.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

from google.colab import files                                       
uploaded = files.upload()
starlist = pd.read_csv("hipp_f1.tsv" , sep=';')
starlist[['Vmag']] = starlist[['Vmag']].apply(pd.to_numeric) 
print(starlist.dtypes)
```

Idealmente esto me debería pasar toda la columna a "float", pero falta varios datos en unas hileras y aparece el error especificado arriba.

Intenté solucionarlo con el siguiente codigo:

```
starlist.Vmag = starlist[pd.to_numeric(starlist.Vmag, errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

Pero esto lo único que hizo fue convertir todos los datos de la columna en NaN y no los que contienen el error (son más de 100.000 datos), ¿como podría omitir los errores y al mismo tiempo transformar la columna en un "float"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Quitar los nan

Tienes que quitar los `NaN`, para que pandas pueda operar con ellos, puedes hacerlo borrando las filas que tengan `NaN` o convirtiendo los `NaN` a un número, que generalmente suele ser cero.

### 2. Cambiar el tipo de columna

Una vez tienes datos operables en todas las columnas ya puedes operar

### Ejemplo

Nos creamos un dataframe y ponemos en **col2** dos `NaN`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


a = pd.DataFrame({'fila1':[1,5,23,5,67,8,3],
                  'fila2':[2,np.nan,34,np.nan,5,4,5],
                  'fila3':[1,2,3,5,6,7,8]})

#Cambiamos los NaN por 0, con el método .fillna() y pasandole un cero
a.fila2 = a.fila2.fillna(int(0))

#Cambiamos el tipo de columna a float con el método .astype() y el tipo de dato.
a.fila2 = a.fila2.astype(float)
```